# how to use expireAfterAccess with CacheBuilder in guava

Tags: java, dictionary, guava

I have the following code:
`new MapMaker().expireAfterAccess(SESSION_EXPIRATION, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).makeMap();`

In guava 10 it said it is deprecated and should be replaced by `CacheBuilder`. What is the new syntax for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The new syntax would look like

```
Cache<K, V> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder().expireAfterAccess(SESSION_EXPIRATION, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS).build();
```

Answer (score 3):

Reading the documentation, I think you might just use the similar methods, and pass a loader which always throws an exception. You would then call `asMap()` to get a map, where you would be able to put your keys and values and have it backed by the cache.

Comment: Cache.asMap().put() works in 10.0.1: http://groups.google.com/group/guava-discuss/browse_thread/thread/f01f7583bb4422d7

Comment: Thanks @eneveu. I've removed the warning from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Guava release 11.0 will feature `CacheBuilder.build()`:

http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder.html

Until then it is unfortunately necessary to use `asMap()`.